# Linear Independence for functions defined by integration

Tags: functional-analysis

I came across this problem while doing some work. I'm been unable to make any progression on it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Given that the set of strictly positive and continuous functions $$f_i(x,y) >0, \quad i=1,\dots,n$$
are linearly independent for $(x,y)  \in [0,1]^2$. Let $g_i$ be defined by
$$
g_i(x) = \int_{y\in [0,1] } f_i(x,y) d y, \quad  i=1,\dots,n
$$
where $g_i$ is unique up to some positive multiple (There is a better way to say this?, say $g_i(x) \neq c g_j(x)$ for some $c >0$ and $i$ &  $j \in \left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$ and $x \in(0,1)$ )

Is the set of functions, $g_1,\ldots,g_n$, also linearly independent for $x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: No, for instance you could have a non-zero function whose integral is zero.

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan - Thanks for your help.  What if the functions are strictly positive? I have added this extra assumption.

Comment: Once again, no. Just take two positive functions with the same integral. For instance, one could be the constant function $1$, and another could be a the same horizontal line with one triangle upward and another downward (to compensate for the area). I hope the imagery is clear :)

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan - Thanks again for you comments. The imagery is clear. I was thinking of the same thing but I didn't know how to put it into context. If I added that the assumption that the $g_i(x)$ are unique would that alleviate the problem? I have added this assumption as well.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to really fix this - just take the previous example, and multiply one of the functions by 2, so that $g_1 = 2g_2$. All in all, the only thing you could expect is that no non-trivial *convex* combination of the $g_i$'s would be zero (assuming the $f_j$ are continuous, of course)

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan - This is all good stuff. Uniqueness would have to be defined up to a scale multiple.

Comment: I find your wording "are linearly independent for $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$" misleading. Perhaps do you mean that the functions are *defined* on the square $[0,1]^2$, and they are $\mathbb R$-linearly independent (that is if $c_1,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb R$ are such that $\sum_{i=1}^nc_if_i(x,y)=0$ **for all** $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$, then each $c_i$ is zero)?

Comment: @Matemáticos Chibchas - Yes to both questions. I'm sorry for the confusion. I believe the solution relies on the fact that the mapping from $f_i$ to $g_i$ is an isomorphism? Any clarity on the problem would be most helpful.

Comment: No. Take $f_1(x,y)=x+1$, $f_2(x,y)=2y$ and $f_3(x,y)=x+2$. Your last scale condition assures that any two of $g_i$'s are not linearly dependent. Since you have many choices for the 2-variable function, I'm pretty sure that even if you ask for any $k$ of the $g_i$'s not being linearly dependent, for $k<n$, then one can construct a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in general. For $n$ a natural number greater than or equal to $3$, let
$$f_i(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l l} (i+1)(xy)^i + (i+1)y^i & \text{for $i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$}\\
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (j+1)(xy)^j + (n-1)& \text{for $i=n$}\end{array}\right.$$
Then the the functions $f_1,...,f_n$ are linearly independent. Let us see why this is so. For any linear combination we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_i+a_n)(i+1)(xy)^i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i(i+1)y^i +a_n(n-1)$$
and since a polynomial is zero if and only if all its coefficients are zero we see that the linear combination is zero if and only if $a_1=a_2=..=a_n=0$.
 However the functions
$$g_i(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l} x^i+1 & \text{for $i\in\{1,..,n-1\}$}\\
\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x^j + (n-1) & \text{for $i=n$}\end{array}\right.$$
are linearly dependent since $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} g_i(x) = g_n(x).$$ One can show more that any $n-1$ of the $g_i$'s are linearly independent (which is much stronger that your requirement that none of them are scalar multiples of each other).

From one of your comments "I believe the solution relies on the fact that the mapping from $f_i$ to $g_i$ is an isomorphism" it seems that you perhaps wanted to ask a different question (since definite integration is far from injective). Perhaps you wanted to ask if $f_i:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g_i : [0,1]\times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ for $i \in \{1,..,n\}$ are functions such that the partial derivative of $g_i$ with respect to $y$ is $f_i$, then $f_1,..,f_n$ being linearly independent implies $g_1,..,g_n$ are linearly independent. This is indeed so since $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i(x,y) = 0$ implies (by taking the partial derivative) that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i f_i(x,y)=0$ which then implies that $a_1=a_2=..=a_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying a few things. Can you suggest some article or books on this material? The function, $g_i$, I'm dealing with is defined through integration.

Comment: Would adding the assumption that for any fixed $y$, the set of functions $f_i(x,y)$ is linearly independent in $x$. Then would the the set of functions $g_i(x)$ be linearly independent as well?

Comment: I think that if we define $f_i(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}x^i + \frac{i+1}{2}(xy)^i + \frac{i+1}{2}y^i + \frac{1}{2}$, $i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$ and kept the same definition for $f_n$, then the $g_i$'s remain the same but I expect you can then prove that for each fixed $y$ the $f_i$'s are linearly independent in $x$. Do you have some particular application in mind?

Comment: Yes I'm dealing with a univariate density formed by integrating out another variable. Do you know any conditions when the above would hold?

Answer (score 0):

**No, it is not (always) linear independent.**
Take $f_1(x,y) := 1+y^2$ and $f_2 = 1+(y-1)^2$ (on $[0,1]^2$).
As far as I understood it, $S:=\{f_1,f_2\}$ is good to go.

$$g_1(x) = 1.5 = g_2(x)\quad \forall x \in [0,1].$$

So this proposition can't be true.

**Possible explanation (no proof)**
You lose information during integration, so they lose their distinction.
The $f_1(x,1-y)=f_2(x,y)\quad \forall x \in[0,1]^2$ is the problem here. The symmetry of the integral kills the difference.